# MySQL select minimum value from a table with a group by

Tags: sql, mysql, select, group-by

Hey everyone
I have a table with an auto increment value called id, an user-id, a date (called date) and an integer for multiple registrations (called multiregistration)
As multiregistration can have more than one date I need to select the multiregistrations with the lowest date first
You can compare it by getting the minimum date for each multiregistration, where I need to get the (id for) each multiregistration. It should then sort them by the minimum date

*Some sample data*

```
 id --- user-id ---   date     --- multiregistration
 1   |    2      |  2010-02-01  |  1
 2   |    3      |  2010-02-01  |  2
 3   |    4      |  2010-01-01  |  2
 4   |    2      |  2010-02-03  |  1
 5   |    4      |  2010-02-03  |  3
 6   |    1      |  2010-02-02  |  3
```

*Expected output*

```
 multiregistration
  2
  1
  3
```

You can compare it to

```
 SELECT `multiregistration`
 FROM `registrations`
 ORDER BY `date`
```

But I want to remove duplicates

Here is the PHP code I am using right now

```
 // Create the query
 $query  = 'SELECT `multiregistration` AS `multireg` FROM `registrations` WHERE `multiregistration`>0 GROUP BY `multiregistration`';

 // Execute the query and set the result into a variable
 $idsTo2ndQuery = arrayExecuteLocalQueryGetResults($query);

 // Create the second Query
 $query2 = 'SELECT `multiregistration` AS `multireg` FROM `registrations` WHERE `multiregistration`='.implode(' OR `multiregistration`=', $idsTo2ndQuery).' ORDER BY `date` ASC';

 // An array of IDs (sorted)
 $ids = array();

 // Execute the query and set the result into a variable
 $idsArray = arrayExecuteLocalQueryGetResults($query2);

 // For each entry
 foreach ($idsArray AS $idArray)
      if (!in_array($idArray, $ids))
           $ids[] = $idArray;

 // Return the IDs
 return $ids;
```

Comment: I think you need to supply some sample data and the expected output from that sample data.

Comment: @Scorpi0 Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by multiregistration, you'll only get one row per distinct multiregistration.  This will give you the set of all the rows sorted by multiregistration first and then date.

```
SELECT multiregistration, date 
FROM registrations 
ORDER BY multiregistration, date
```

UPDATE:

This will give you a set of ids...one for each distinct multiregistration where the date is the min(date)...

```
SELECT id  
FROM registrations 
GROUP BY multiregistration
ORDER BY multiregistration, date
```

UPDATE:

This will give you a one multiregistration record...where the date is the first date in the table...

```
SELECT top 1 multiregistration  
FROM registrations     
ORDER BY date
```

UPDATE: 
(sample data?)

```
ID-----USER-ID-----DATE------------MULTIREGISTRATION
1        101            1/2/2011         3
2        101            1/1/2011         3 
3        102            1/5/2011         2
4        102            1/7/2011         2
5        103            1/1/2011         4
```

Minumum date is 1/1/2011 multiregistration (3) would be 1/1/2011 - id 2... 
This will return an ordered (by ascending date) result set where the multiregistration value is 3

```
SELECT * 
FROM registrations   
WHERE ID in (SELECT min(date) FROM registrations)   
ORDER BY date
```

For both (actually in this case all 3 - #3, 2, and 4) in a list...the following would return a result set (shown below...)

```
SELECT * 
FROM registrations          
ORDER BY multiregistration, date
```

This returns a result set like

```
3        102            1/5/2011         2
4        102            1/7/2011         2
2        101            1/1/2011         3 
1        101            1/2/2011         3
5        103            1/1/2011         4
```

Comment: I only need the IDs of the Multiregistration

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood me<br /> I need the multiregistration, but it should not be sorted by multiregistration only by date (and it should be the 1st date of the multiregistration)

Comment: So your looking for an integer value (a count?) stored in multiregistration for the first (earliest) date in the table? Or... are you looking for an integer value (a count) stored in multiregistration for the first (earliest) date for each distinct user_id?

Comment: You can compare it by getting the minimum date for each multiregistration, where I need to get the (id for) each multiregistration. It should then sort them by the minimum date

Comment: It was a bit of what I am searching, but I need both to output<br /> And I should not timeout, as this did in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: It was a kind of what I am searching, but I only need to select the each ID of the multiregistration once

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this in T-SQL. It declares a variable table to play with the data and the query produces the exact result requested.

```
DECLARE @A AS TABLE(ID INT, USERID INT, SOMEDATE DATE, MULTIREG INT)

INSERT @A
SELECT 1,2,'20100201',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3,'20100201',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,4,'20100101',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2,'20100302',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,4,'20100203',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,1,'20100202',3

SELECT * FROM @A AS A
WHERE A.SOMEDATE = (SELECT MIN(SOMEDATE) FROM @A AS B WHERE B.MULTIREG = A.MULTIREG)
ORDER BY USERID DESC

ID  USERID  SOMEDATE     MULTIREG
3    4     2010-01-01       2
1    2     2010-02-01       1
6    1     2010-02-02       3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(date), `multiregistration` 
FROM `registrations` 
GROUP BY `multiregistration` 
ORDER by `date`
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick.<br /> I even tried with SELECT DISTINCT `multiregistration` AS `multiregID` FROM `registrations` ORDER BY `date`

Comment: @The87Boy - Do you get any error? or can you put down some sample output expected in your question?

Comment: I can try to explain what I want again <br /> I need to select the ID of the multiregistrations either by group by or DISTINCT, and it should by sorted by the date. I do not get any errors

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT multiregistration FROM registrations 
GROUP BY multiregistration ORDER BY date
```

is it doing the work?